Why is the --integrity switch in cryptsetup luksFormat still considered experimental?
As of 2024, the --integrity switch in cryptsetup luksFormat is still marked as experimental in the cryptsetup manpage:
WARNING:  This  extension  is EXPERIMENTAL and requires dm-integrity kernel target (available since kernel version 4.12).
For native AEAD modes, also enable "User-space interface for AEAD cipher algorithms" in "Cryptographic API" section (CONFIG_CRYPTO_USER_API_AEAD .config option).

Note that kernel 4.12 was released in 2017.
But I haven't found any explanation why it is still experimental. This is a problem, since a combination of LUKS and dm-integrity is ideal for me. I want my external hard drives to be encrypted, and I want metadata for data integrity verification. Some filesystems have checksums (btrfs and ZFS), but I want to be able to use multiple file systems on the external hard drives to not have to rely on one filesystem. Ideally, with dm-integrity, I could for example use ext4 on the external drive and still detect data corruption.
So, does anybody know why that switch is still experimental? And, is it safe to use in certain use cases despite its experimental status?
